# Manipulating strings containing backslash

Tags: string-manipulation, internet

I'm trying to implement some code that downloads files from some webpages.

I am using the built-in functions `Import` and `StringReplace`.

I found that when I import a url that contain blanks I need to replace them with %20, however in some strings "\" appears suddenly.

For example,

```
StringReplace[http://ww.aaa.com/asd/dfh asda asd.pdf, " " -> "%20"]
```

I expect this to give "http://www.aaa.com/asd/dfh%20asda%20asd.pdf".

Using this string with `FetchURL`, I try to download the file but it does not work.

I found that when I copy the same string and paste it somewhere, it looks like:

> http://www.aaa.com/asd/dfh%20asda%20asd.\pdf

I suspect that the "\" is causing the problem. What's the proper way to deal with "\" characters here?

Comment: StringReplace["hptt://ww.aaa\.com/asd/dfh asda asd.pdf", {" "->"%20", "\\"->""}] returns "hptt://ww.aaa.com/asd/dfh%20asda%20asd.pdf" Be sure to use two backslash in the pattern.

Comment: A better approach is to use `URLEncode["yourstring"]` ([docs here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLEncode.html)) that will take care of all the URL encoding for you.

Comment: I would guess there is something odd/non-ascii in your original string.

Comment: @Bill As you said I tried that but does not work. However, recently I found that when I copied my string with "Plain Text Copy" , it worked perpectly. Can you see what is the problems??

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
URLSave @ "http://geniusquotes.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/The-quieter-you-become.jpg"
```

**Reference:**

[URLSave](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLSave.html)

**Tutorial:**

[Web Operations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WebOperations.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might try two possibilities (or both) and let me know if the problem persists:

```
arg = "your string";

str1 = StringReplace[ToString[arg], "\[Continuation] " -> ""];

str2 = ImportString[ExportString[str1, "Text"], "Text"];
```

Do str1 or str2 still contain the symbol you see?

Comment: Also I tried your way but result was negative. As you can see comment to bill,  I found that when I copied my string with "Plain Text Copy" , it worked perpectly.  Can you see the problem?